# How to use local docker image with openshift online?

Tags: openshift, redhat, redhat-containers

Hello every one i just want to know is it possible to use my local docker image for containers in redhat openshift online free trial version https://www.openshift.com/trial/ (the one that has test drive over it)? As far as i have searched there are some solutions but that dont seem to work with this openshift online free trial, also i want to know why am i bening asked to enter password again in the profile form when i try to install openshift cli?

Comment: It's recommended that you reach out to community support at https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html, since they could help you with more specific information. But generally, you can `docker login` and `docker push/pull` images from your local machine directly to the internal OpenShift registry. Regarding installing the `oc` CLI, without knowing the link that you're using, or having more information, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this awesome youtube video, I was able to successfully deploy my local docker image onto the dedicated openshift platform's docker registry with the help of this: [Push local docker images to openshift registry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5VzXvvkiL4) - minishift

For deploying from local system you may need to do similar steps, only thing that would be slightly different is that in the video he has a local instance, whereas you would be referring to the online openshift cluster. You would be logging into the docker registry of the online openshift cluster from your local system using the oc cli.

Hope it helps.